# Edit Nested JSON Keys in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json object like so

```
{
    "scenefile": {
        "globaldata": {
            "diffusecoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            },
            "specularcoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            },
            "ambientcoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            }
        },
        "cameradata": { ... },
        "lightdata": [ 
            {"light1": 
                {"strength": {"value": 5}}   
            },
            {"light2": 
                {"strength": {"value": 10}}   
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My issue is that I want to get rid of the "v" keys. So it would become

```
{
    "scenefile": {
        "globaldata": {
            "diffusecoeff": "0.5",
            "specularcoeff": "0.5",
            "ambientcoeff": "0.5"
        },

        "cameradata": {
            ...
        },
        "lightdata": [
            {"light1": {"strength": 5}},
            {"light2": {"strength": 10}}
        ]
    }
}
```

What is stumping me is that there are several cases of

```
"attribute": {
    "v": someValue
 }
```

All throughout the nested json file (not just in the format mentioned above), and so I am looking for a way to quickly change all of those to just be

```
"attribute": someValue
```

Comment: Do you want to get rid of the keys in the _json file_, or in the _in-memory python dictionary object_?

Comment: the in-memory python dict as that gets converted to json

Comment: That's not valid JSON, and `ambientcoeff` isn't in the input. Please [edit] to fix it.

Comment: The json should be valid now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function.

If the parameter is a dictionary, loop over its elements. If any of them is a dictionary with just one element, and the key begins with `v`, replace the dictionary with the nested value. Otherwise, recurse into the value.

If the parameter is a list, iterate over its elements and recurse into each element.

```
def replace_values_recursive(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for key, value in data.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict) and len(value) == 1 and next(iter(value)).startswith('v'):
                data[key] = next(iter(value.values()))
            else:
                replace_values_recursive(value)
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        for value in data:
            replace_values_recursive(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the elements of that one dictionary, replacing each value with the nested `v` key's value.

```
data = {
    "scenefile": {
        "globaldata": {
            "diffusecoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            },
            "specularcoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            },
            "ambientcoeff": {
                "v": "0.5"
            }
        },
        "cameradata": { ... },
        "lightdata": [ ... ]
    }
}

globaldata = data['scenefile']['globaldata']
for key, value in globaldata.items():
    globaldata[key] = value['v']

pprint.pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'scenefile': {'cameradata': {Ellipsis},
               'globaldata': {'ambientcoeff': '0.5',
                              'diffusecoeff': '0.5',
                              'specularcoeff': '0.5'},
               'lightdata': [Ellipsis]}}
```

This doesn't touch the rest of the dictionary, so other `v` keys are left alone.

Comment: Sorry I just fixed the question, I was having trouble getting all of the v keys removed (so the nested ones too)

Comment: I tested my code, it removes the nested v keys just as I said.

Comment: `This doesn't touch the rest of the dictionary, so other v keys are left alone.` Sorry I meant the other v keys in the dictionary unless you are saying that it does touch the entire dictionary

Comment: What other v keys? This removes all the v keys you showed in your example.

Comment: ```The issue is that the "v" keys are also present in other parts of the json file too``` I didn't put in other "v" keys in the specific example because there was not a specific pattern to the "v" keys other than it being ```attribute : {"v": value}```. The reason why I was having trouble is because it does not seem to be something a for loop can solve because there can be nested "v" keys in all parts of the json that are not just at the top level. For example in ```cameradata``` there could be a few attribute with "v" key pairs but then also a deeper json object that also has "v" key pairs

Comment: Are they all at the same nesting level, or do you need a recursive solution that looks for `v` at any level?

Comment: Please update the example to show more general problem.

Comment: And yes it would be a recursive solution, or preferably a library that has some functionality to handle that

Comment: There are no more `v` keys. The edit has `value` keys.

Comment: How is the code supposed to know which nested keys should be removed?

Comment: I would want all of the "v" attributes to be removed. So anytime it finds a "v" attribute it would edit its parents to use the value itself rather than the nested "v" dict

Comment: But `value` is not `v`. Unless you mean any key where `v` is the first letter?

Comment: Should it only be dictionaries that have just one key that begins with `v`?

Comment: Yes, its only the ones that follow the form 

"attribute": {
    "v": someValue
 }
Where the dictionary only contains that one value "v". However the "attribute" could have been 1 of many attributes of its parent dict

Comment: I've been getting errors trying to edit this answer. I posted a new answer with the code you want.